# It's Damn Madness!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

- Ikej omeq ngelsy, rchesy, rm ominoesb
- Egg hutn holidya
- Aeus's xife bnd tister
- Ersonal istory, riefly
- Pni shperica Nnitend cahracte
- Nagro htiw a lanac
- Britsh molases
- "Stwelft Mnigh" oprotagonis
- Bodloo vosessel oor molinera doseposit
- Kren Wr bockae lcatin
- Htneetenn6 yrutnc3 Naissr3 resopmc4 Verikalb5

[image]

This puzzle pays tribute to a certain duo.
What is something they (and people like them) might get?

[Google sheets version](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k7kWPc8F7CZ3V6FhayFvz9ydK1KqEOrSgu23Q2Vcw0k/edit#gid=1917017355)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Continuing from cap's answer,

> cap had filled out the grid with song titles from [Autechre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autechre) and the black letters spelled out "Eleventh Album". Autechre's eleventh album is [Exai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exai), and its cover art is an 11x11 grid of black and gray pixels, the same size as the grid we have. Keeping the letters in their places but replacing the background colors by the album cover we get the following:[image: grid of letters with album background]
> The black squares spell out our answer, RAVE REVIEWS!

Comment: Nice! That makes sense with the title too.

Answer (score 11):

Almost complete answer..

The duo is

> Autechre

and they might get

> album eleven

Each clue is

> wordplay on a classic crossword clue. The same wordplay must then be applied to the answer to get a song by the duo. I have yet to work out two of the wordplays.
>  [image]

Then fill in the grid

> by the songs' years
>  [image]

Take the

> black cells and they spell out "ALBUM ELEVEN"

I'm not sure why

> the grid is arranged as it is...

Comment: rot13(NYOHZ RYRIRA) is not the correct final answer. Keep going...

Comment: The wordplay for the one before last is rot13(erzbir frpbaq naq frpbaq-gb-ynfg yrggref - xBerNa jNe oYbpxnQr yBpngvBa) and the last one is rot13(erirefr jbeq nsgre erzbivat frpbaq yrggre, nccraq jvgu ahzore bs yrggref erznvavat zvahf 3)

Comment: Of course, rot13(gurve ryriragu nyohz vf RKNV - lbh znl arrq gb nccyl shegure genafsbezngvbaf gb gung gb trg gur svany nafjre?)